# Dynamic 3D Animation/Simulation of a street based on a file input

Tags: 3d, directx, game-engine, game-physics, direct3d

I want to dynamically generate a 3D animation of a street based on the input from a file. **A** car is moving inside the street lane in a variable speed.

Target platform: Desktop Windows 7 SP1 64 bit.

**Street Properties:**

- Just the road without landscape (no trees, no buildings, etc.)
- Only one car is moving on the street (inside the lane/circuit)
- Has curvature and slope (uphill and downhill). Dynamically generate street. i.e. In a file I would be having values something like

```
Length (in meters)   Curvature(in angle)     Uphill (in angle)   Downhill(in angle) 

    1000                    -                           -                20°
    300                     20° (left)                  -                -
    500                     5°  (right)                30°               -
```

This means, For 1 kilometre the street is straight with 20° downhill. The next 300 meters the street has 20° curve towards left direction (no uphill and no downhill). After that for the next 500 meters the street has 5° curvature towards right direction with 30° uphill.

The car movement on the street should be visualised as chase cam view. This might not be a gaming development, but in some sense dynamic simulation or animation, because car moves in a predefined speed inside the lane and user is not controlling the movement of the car.

In a typical [car game development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok7Tw6-nCss), the model of the street/race circuit is already developed and in place when the game starts. I am a Direct2D developer and I am wondering if my requirement can be implemented at all. If yes, some hints or tutorials or the technologies that need to be used to accomplish my requirements would be of great help! Thx.

Comment: What you want to accomplish is possible, though I think your question in its current form is too broad for SO.  The answer involves a huge range of APIs and concepts.  Your best bet is probably to find something similar that someone else has already done like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5Snsi68xzE).

Comment: Thx! Based on my student level research, the concept I need to use is procedural graphic generation. Programmatically (C++/Scripts) I need to keep extending the street model in the runtime. Do you happen to know some tutorial? As of now, I plan to use Blender software.

Comment: Your goal is too specific for there to be a tutorial describing exactly what you need to do.  You'll need to find information on the separate aspects, and combine the information yourself.  For example, you're likely to find a tutorial on generating road data based on segments like in your text file; and you're likely to find one on how to generate 3D geometry at runtime; but you're unlikely to find one that describes how to do both simultaneously.